# set encoding of string literals to latin1 with gcc

Tags: c++, c, encoding, iso-8859-1, latin1

Is there any way to force the gcc to use latin1 encoding for string literals? I can use the u8 prefix to get utf-8 encoded string literals, but how can I use iso 8859-1 string literals? Do not misunderstand me, I'm not talking about the encoding of the source files

Comment: If you want a specific encoding for string literals, you most definitely want to set the encoding of the source files, as string literals are in the source files.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include latin1 literals in source files, you should use `\x` directly. There are probably other ways, but they rely on non-portable options for telling the compiler the encoding of your source file, and you've already said you don't want to change the encoding of your source file. But really, this is 2014, not 1994. You should avoid using latin1 if at all possible and have all your data in a Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) but since the question is about gcc specifically:

You need to use the option:

```
-fexec-charset=iso-8859-1
```

You might also want to specify the encoding of the source file, using the `-finput-charset` option. Finally, you can specify the encoding of wide chars, but it's really highly unrecommended.

All three of these options are described in the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fexec-charset-999).